# multiple launch files lead to multiple log directories

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roscore, rosrun, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i have multiple launch files which are started from a shell script after the booting of the computer which is on the robot.
For some reason this creates multiple directories in $HOME/.ros/log. To find the correct logfiles if we have to debug something is kind of annoying as the files are in all of the directories and we have to check quite a few to find the file which has the newest data written into.

Is there a setting to set the log dir for all nodes? The ones started from roslaunch as well as the roscore which is started with the roscore command and the nodes with are running from rosrun.

thank you.
bajo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193198/multiple-launch-files-lead-to-multiple-log-directories./) by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-09-22**:
Can you maybe just include all launch files in a single launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought so as well. But I think i found the problem now, thanks to gvdhoorn mentioning the `run_id`.
It seems that we have the `run_id` in a parameter file which we load with `roslaunch`. This caused the second log directory.
I removed the run_id from the parameter file now, but this file is sometimes created by our partners so i cann't make sure this does not happen again from time to time. Maybe there a way not to load the run_id parameter.

Anyway. Thank you gvdhoorn and dornhege for your help.

---

Originally posted by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) with karma: 206 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you launch a single `roscore` prior to loading your launch files, shouldn't they all reuse that running instance?

From [wiki.ros.org/roscore](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore):

> NOTE: If you use roslaunch, it will automatically start roscore if it detects that it is not already running.

As far as I know, the directory where logfiles end up is determined at the start of `roscore` (see the `runid` parameter, and [roscpp/Overview/Logging#Output](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging#Output)), so all subsequently started nodes' logs should be written to the `~/.ros/log/<runid>/whatever` directories.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1